# Weird Swing Glitch?

Tags: java, swing

I don't understand this, I'm currently making a main menu for a game i'm making but for some reason when I hover over a JButton, it flashes up on the top left side of the JFrame. I don't have any mouseAction methods or anything, is it the gif i'm using? I'm not sure...

Here is a screengrab of the error

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTUmP.png]

Here is my code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainMenu {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frasergatchi");

public void display(){
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void addComponents(){
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    JButton instructions = new JButton("Instructions");
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    paintMenu paintMenu = new paintMenu();

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    frame.add(panel);

    play.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    instructions.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    exit.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    panel.add(paintMenu);
    panel.add(play);
    panel.add(instructions);
    panel.add(exit);
}

public class paintMenu extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics){
        Image dog = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("DogMenuImage.gif")).getImage();
        graphics.drawImage(dog,170,240,this);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first statement in the `paintComponent()` method should always be:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

to make sure the background gets cleared.

Also:

1. Don't do I/O in a painting method. Painting methods are for painting only. Read the image in the constructor of your class and same the image in an instance variable.
2. Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Think of all the classes in the JDK and follow the standards.
3. There is no need to create a custom class to paint the image. Just use a JLabel with an Icon.

Comment: thanks man, im new to swing you see, thought this was weird, thanks! :)

Comment: MainMenu does start with uppercase ;) but ill take your first advice! ive got to wait 6 mins to mark your answer as answered

Comment: @FraserAngus the class paintMenu should be PaintMenu

Comment: @markbernard ahh now I see, i thought inner classes could have method like names! thank you very much!